# Validating more then on text field in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation

Hi I'm validating  more then one text field its not working properly for example if have 4 fields means its validation works on 3 fields its not working on 4th i have trying use else if in objective c like how we use normally in c and other languages but the else if is not available please tell me how to resolve this issues.

```
       - (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
     if ([name.text length] > 25 && [city.text length] > 25) {
         UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls enter less then 25 character in name and city" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert1 show];
         [alert1 release];     
      }

    if ([self validateEmail:[email text]] != 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Pls enter valid email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];
      }

    if ([self phonevalidate:[phone text]] != 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Pls enter only 10 numbers" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];
       }

   if ([name.text length] < 1 && [city.text length] < 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls fill the empty field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];    
      }

  else {
         pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];

    //pollpoliticalViewController *vc2 = [[pollpoliticalViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:pollVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Thanks For The Registration" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
      }
     }
```

In this above code the first validation is not working please tell is there is an another way to validation more then one text field or please tell me where I'm doing wrong in this above code.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you log the `length` of the text of the two UITextField?

Comment: @Larme i want the less then 25 character in my uitextfield

Comment: You need to use if, elsif, elsif, elsif, else, or you need to remove the else and add a return in each of your if.

Comment: You're saying it's not working. First of all, check that the value tested are correct.

Comment: Elseif does exist in Objective C, and works exactly the same way as in C. So does switch

Comment: Also, why are you not using ARC?

Comment: @Larme sorry its validating and showing the alert but the problem its going next view controller after showing the validating error i will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...the else if is not available...*

`else if` is available in Objective C.

```
if () {
} else if () {
} else if () {
} else {
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

> Objective-C is a thin layer on top of C, and moreover is a strict
>   superset of C; it is possible to compile any C program with an
>   Objective-C compiler, and to freely include C code within an
>   Objective-C class.[7]
>
> Objective-C derives its object syntax from Smalltalk. All of the
>   syntax for non-object-oriented operations (including primitive
>   variables, pre-processing, expressions, function declarations, and
>   function calls) are identical to that of C, while the syntax for
>   object-oriented features is an implementation of Smalltalk-style
>   messaging.

Comment: Note that "else if" isn't actually a construct in the C family of languages.  It's merely an else followed by another if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the else if syntax

```
- (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
    if ([name.text length] > 25 && [city.text length] > 25) {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls enter less then 25 character in name and city" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];     
    } else if ([self validateEmail:[email text]] != 1) {
        // Show Alert
    } else if ([self phonevalidate:[phone text]] != 1) {
        // Show Alert
    } else if ([name.text length] < 1 && [city.text length] < 1) {
        // Show Alert
    } else {
        // Everything passed
        pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];
        [self presentViewController:pollVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Thanks For The Registration" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Or, add some return like so :

```
- (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
    if ([name.text length] > 25 && [city.text length] > 25) {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"pls enter less then 25 character in name and city" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];
        return;    
    if ([self validateEmail:[email text]] != 1) {
        // Show Alert
        return;
    }
    if ([self phonevalidate:[phone text]] != 1) {
        // Show Alert
        return;
    }
    if ([name.text length] < 1 && [city.text length] < 1) {
        // Show Alert
        return;
    }
    // Everything passed
    pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];
    [self presentViewController:pollVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Thanks For The Registration" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```